# FME - ImageRasterizer fails to detect resolution of existing raster file

Tags: fme-form

I have a .ecw raster that I read in and then converted into a polygon using BoundingBoxAccumulator transformer.

I am now trying to rasterize this polygon using ImageRasterizer into the same resolution as the orginial raster. If I define an exact number of columns/rows of cells, the process works.

However, if I define the number of columns and rows by referencing the original .ecw, it fails. (Inside ImageRasterizer, I define the number of cells as '$(SourceDataset_ECW)')

> ImageRasterizer(VectorToRasterFactory): Cannot convert 'WIDTH' value
>   of 'C:\input.ecw' The value may be out of range or in wrong format. 
>   Please see factory documentation for specific range or format

Comment: I don't have access to FME right now, but you should be able to expose the ECW attributes which contain the rows and columns.  You should then be able to use those attributes in your imagerasterizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Fezter's hint, it seems what I needed was an extra transformer:

RasterPropertiesExtractor

Which allows referencing of _num_columns and _num_rows rather than '$(SourceDataset_ECW)' - which apparenetly does not contain any information about columns and rows.